# Snippets for productivity - collect good code

Tags: code-snippets, knowledge-management

I was wondering whether there're recommendable sites, that host collections of good and useful code-snippets.

Searching stackoverflow, to be honest, sometimes is priceless. 
- But if you know sites like [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse) (just for Shell stuff), you may also want something like that for Ruby, Java, Python or C#. There're some small collections, of course. Very often these are specific sites dedicated to be just [funny](http://govnokod.ru/) or "wicked cool" (the book series).

I'm just looking for practical stuff to learn from other people's experiences. The standard stuff. Not funny, not wicked. Just pragmatic and workflow-oriented. It seems no one wants to share that.

If you're simply googeling the web and put everything into a growing list of files, there's no overview. So that's not the workflow either, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Not really snippets. But quite useful, http://github.com
- With many languages, there is http://snippets.dzone.com/
- Still with many languages, there is http://codesnippets.joyent.com/
- For Django, there is http://www.djangosnippets.org/

After, there's a lot of blogs all other the web giving advices and snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Some others:

- [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/)
- [RefactorMyCode](http://refactormycode.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com) and [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com) have lots of code snippets which are useful